# HTML: Horizantly align span text to an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align span text with an image horizontally:

```
<div >
      <img src="c:\work\img\logo3.jpg" width="80" height="80" />
      <span><ul>YAD<li>HIM</li></ul></span>
    </div>
```

Reason of putting words in `<ul>` is achieve linebreak.

For more refer:http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/4LKhX/

Comment: The only content allowed in a `<ul>` are `<li>` elements. So your 'YAD' inside the `<ul>` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align them centrally add `text-align: center;` to `div.box` and remove the `margin-left` from `span`. Also add `display: block;` to `span` and then you can get rid of the `<ul>YAD<li>HIM</li></ul>` mess.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/

Comment: To achieve what I want I just have to change display:inline-block. Thanks

Comment: I think I get what you actually wanted now too. Not what I put... You should get rid of the `ul` stuff though.

Comment: Sure. Is there any way to align first word with the image's top?

Comment: Maybe playing round with the `margin-top` for the `span`. (-8px or semething). Not sure this would be the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/8/

```
div.box {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  //margin-left: 10%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  clear:both;
  display: block;
}
#mymessage{
       padding-top: 50%;
}
```